# Cannot write help text to a file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I was trying to write help text to a file with

```
Set-Content -path "help.txt" -Value $(help -Full "help")
```

Then I found that `help` cmdlet generates an object rather than text.
But simply adding `toString()` at the end does not work either.

So how can I get clean text from `help` command and write it to file using `Set-Content`?

Comment: `get-help help | out-file help.txt` works fine for me...

Comment: `help` is a proxy command, wrapping `Get-Help |more` - please use `Get-Help` rather than `help`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: The OP's problem actually only surfaces _with_ `Get-Help` (I suspect that in the OP's case `help` is a mere _alias_ for it rather than the default screen-paging wrapper function). With the default `help` wrapper function in place, compare `(get-help -full get-help)[0].GetType().Name` to `(help -full help)[0].GetType().Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to capture output *as it would print on the screen*, use either output redirection operator `>`, or pipe to cmdlet [`Out-File`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx), which is required if you want to use an output character encoding other than the default, UTF-16 LE:

```
help -full help > help.txt  # invariably creates a UTF-16 LE file
help -full help | Out-File help.txt # equivalent, but supports -Encoding <name>
```

By contrast, [`Set-Content`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849828.aspx):

- does *not* use PowerShell's default output formatting; instead, it applies (at least conceptually) a `.ToString()` call to each input object, which may or may not give a meaningful representation.
- creates *ASCII* files by default, but, like `Out-File`, it supports different encodings via the
  `-Encoding` parameter.

Comment: Just what *does* use `$OutputEncoding`?  `>` doesn't.  If `Set-Content` doesn't, then I assume `Add-Content` doesn't.  Is `Out-File` it?

Comment: $OutputEncoding is used for output to external CLIs. > invariably and Out-File by default use UTF16 LE. Both Out-File and Set-Content / Add-Content allow you to choose a different encoding with -Encoding <encoding>.

Comment: That's just weird.  Then again, these are the same people who thought `Export-Csv` should have `-NoTypeInformation` instead of `-IncludeTypeInformation`.

Comment: @BaconBits: I do wish PS had followed the .NET framework's lead in consistently defaulting to UTF-8 encoding - both on input and output. With respect to `Export-Csv`, it arguably makes sense to default to _including_ type information, so that round-tripping the data is possible (at least with primitive data types), consistent with `Export-Clixml`; strangely, though, `Export-Csv` defaults to _ASCII_ encoding too, just like `Set-Content` / `Add-Content`.